# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.1.0... The system cannot find the file specified. (It's already loaded in my GAC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, dll, .net-assembly

I'm trying to run my web app which references Oracle.Web, which is already loaded in my GAC:

[image]

When I run my web app, I get the error message:

[image]

The Oracle.Web DLL is 32-bit.

**EDIT**: Here's a printout of the assembly bind failure log for Oracle.Web.  Basically, it fails to load from the GAC:

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (6/19/2013 @ 10:20:49 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.Web,
>   Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/blah/HR/ForHR/HRWS/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = C:\blah\HR\ForHR\HRWS\bin LOG:
>   Dynamic Base =
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\HRws\c1e0f910 LOG: Cache Base =
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\HRws\c1e0f910 LOG: AppName = 1f90b2c5 Calling assembly :
>   (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\blah\HR\ForHR\HRWS\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342 LOG: GAC Lookup was
>   unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/HRws/c1e0f910/1f90b2c5/Oracle.Web.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/HRws/c1e0f910/1f90b2c5/Oracle.Web/Oracle.Web.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/blah/HR/ForHR/HRWS/bin/Oracle.Web.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/blah/HR/ForHR/HRWS/bin/Oracle.Web/Oracle.Web.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/HRws/c1e0f910/1f90b2c5/Oracle.Web.EXE. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/HRws/c1e0f910/1f90b2c5/Oracle.Web/Oracle.Web.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/blah/HR/ForHR/HRWS/bin/Oracle.Web.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/blah/HR/ForHR/HRWS/bin/Oracle.Web/Oracle.Web.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

**QUESTION**: Does anyone have any ideas as to why I'm having this issue?

Comment: Well, what happened when you followed the advice in the error and turned logging on?

Comment: @EricLippert Please see edited post above.

Comment: I'm not so sure `C:\Windows\assembly` is the actual location of GAC. How did you load the assembly into GAC? Did you just copy it into that directory?

Comment: You say `The Oracle.Web DLL is 32-bit.` but is try to load the 64bit, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll`  do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this didn't work, but what I did was simply install the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of ODAC 11.2 Release 5, which took care of registering all required assemblies in the GAC, among several other tasks I'm sure.  Once installed, I ran the app, and it worked fine.  Thanks to all that have contributed to this.

Answer (score 4):

You need enable it for 32 bit application in the application pool your website from IIS.

open **IIS>application pool> Enable 32 bit application= true**